# json and jquery autocomplete - need help to understand what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, json

> ```
> <form action="" method="get" style="margin-left: 2em">
>   <input id="companies" type="text" name="company" value="" size="40" />
>   <button type="submit" class="button-search">Search</button>
> </form>
> ```

my json comes from this

http://localhost:8080/;companies?name=aba

and returns a valid json like:

> {"name": "aba", "title": "Aba"}, {"name": "abak", "title": "Abak"}]

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#companies").autocomplete({
    source: ";companies",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // perhaps do something with these?
      name = ui.item.name;
      title = ui.item.title;
   }
});
});
</script>
```

i get no results in the list being displayed!

what am i missing here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jqueryui autocomplete doc/demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote), the url parameter is "term", not "name".

So, `http://localhost:8080/;companies?term=aba` should return the expected json, instead of `http://localhost:8080/;companies?name=aba` which you're using now.

Comment: one more thing, i forgot to ask. if i want to pass the selected item so that a new select list is available how can this be done? something like the 'country', 'region', 'county' select where a user selects a country then a list is returned of the regions and then the county list is built?